# C# ASP.NET - User keystroke validation and input character into correct place

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, blazor, keystroke

I am looking to have a time field that starts with 00:00 which is the exact format I want.

As the user types the time I want to read the keystroke and place it within my preassigned value.

--Edit-- removed previous validation code which didn't really pertain to finding out how to validate upon keystroke.

Comment: Quite a comprehensive spec, how much are you prepared to pay for this time field?  Joking aside, where are you using it and what have you done besides some rudimentary code?  I would suggest considering some form of regular expression checker instead of all that convoluted logic.

Comment: This code isn't all that important I am really looking for how to run scripts per keystroke instead of on say a submit button.

Comment: The code is *very* important because the question is unclear. You can use `input type='time'` for starters. You can validate keystrokes with client code. In fact, if the `blazor` tag is valid, you can easily use C# to validate the contents. There are some fancy time picker components too

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you use the built in textmode = time.

It not 100% as you ask, but your specification has some "issues".

for example, if I want 10:30, or 1:30?

so, a 1, and a 3 for 10:03 don't make sense, since I might want:

```
 1:03
10:03
 1:30
10:30
```

So, hitting a 1, and then a 3 CAN'T really result in 10:03, since then how would you enter 10:30?

As I stated, you probably best to use the default text mode = time.

It will do MOST of what you ask, does not allow user to enter NON number chars, and formats for most of what you want.

So, say I want 10:30

If I enter 1,0,3, then that's what I get
e.g., this:

Markup:

```
       <h3>enter time</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" runat="server"
            TextMode="Time">
        </asp:TextBox>
```

So, for 10:30, then 1,0,3

[image]

Now, of course above has AM/PM

We just have to try and google, and see if am/pm can be removed.

And if you need more then 12 hours, then again, the above may well not help you.

Comment: Thanks for this snippet, it should probably do the job.  
I was really looking for someway to have the server validate per keystroke.  Whether it be a time field or not doesn't really matter, it just happens to be what I am working on at the moment.  I am new to ASP.net but in FileMaker I was able to basically accept what a users types and if it validated then it was ok otherwise it just posted back the same string.  On the user end it just looks like it prevents characters from being typed as they don't see it work.  I am looking to have that same feature just in this platform.

Comment: `someway to have the server validate per keystroke.` *why*? That offers nothing except increase traffic and the server's workload, *and* delay the UI. If you use Blazor Server, everything already runs on the server. Post your code

Answer (score -1):

So here is what I found to validate as the user types.

It still shows what they typed before it removes it but it was as close as I could get.

Also if anyone knows a way to pass the parameters in from the eventclick without having to declare them in the function so I can reuse this on multiple fields passing in the different variables would be great!

Basically I setup a session for per user bases that will hold the value of the field when a key is pressed down in memory and when released it will pass the new value through a validation check and if it passes then all good otherwise it resets the value with what is in the memory storage.

Under the program.cs I added

--code

```
//Use for session control
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
});

var app = builder.Build();
// end the Session Control 

// Add the Session Control then go to SessionController
app.UseSession();
```

Under the Session Controller

--code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Products.Models;

namespace Products.Controllers
{
    public class SessionController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
        public SessionController(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }
        public FieldModel EventHandler(FieldModel model)
        {
            string sessionName = model.sessionName;
            
            if (model.keystroke == "down")
            {
                //This is passing in the current value of the field.  Just need to save it in the Session
                string fieldString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
                _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(sessionName, fieldString);
            }
            else if (model.keystroke == "up")
            {
                //TODO - This is passing in the new character. Get the session
                FieldModel priorModel = new FieldModel();
                string fieldString = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString(sessionName);
                priorModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FieldModel>(fieldString);

                bool validate = false;
                //TODO - This is passing in the new character.  Validate the value for the field
                if (model.fieldType == "time")
                {
                    if (model.fieldNewValue.Length < 5)
                        validate = true;
                }
                //TODO - If validation passes allow the update
                if (validate == true)
                {
                    //fieldString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
                    //_contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(sessionName, fieldString);
                    
                }
                //TODO - If validation fails reset the field to the current value
                else
                {
                    //fieldString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(priorModel);
                    //_contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(sessionName, fieldString);
                    model = priorModel;
                }
            }
            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

For the webpage view I used the following code
--code

```
<script>

    function FieldValidatorD() {
        let sessionName_ = `time`;
        let fieldID_ = `time`;
        let fieldType_ = `time`
        let keystroke_ = `down`
        let input = document.querySelector(`#` + fieldID_).value;        
        let json = {
          sessionName: sessionName_,
          fieldID: fieldID_,
          fieldType: fieldType_,
          fieldCurrentValue: input,
          fieldNewValue: input,
          keystroke: keystroke_
        };        
     //console.log(json);
        $.ajax({
            type: `json`,
            data: json,
            url: `/Session/EventHandler`,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
                //console.log(data.fieldNewValue);
            }
        })
    };
    function FieldValidatorU() {
        let sessionName_ = `time`;
        let fieldID_ = `time`;
        let fieldType_ = `time`
        let keystroke_ = `up`
        let input = document.querySelector(`#`+fieldID_).value;
        let json = {
            sessionName: sessionName_,
            fieldID: fieldID_,
            fieldType: fieldType_,
            fieldCurrentValue: input,
            fieldNewValue: input,
            keystroke: keystroke_
        };
        //console.log(json);
        $.ajax({
            type: `json`,
            data: json,
            url: `/Session/EventHandler`,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
               //console.log(data);
               //console.log(data.fieldNewValue);
                //fill in the textbox by injecting the html into the field
                $(`#` + fieldID_).val(data.fieldNewValue);
            }
        })
    };
 

</script>
```

Comment: You used the `blazor` tag. This isn't Blazor code nor is any of this needed. Why call the *server* to validate* client* values? Why not use an [input type='time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) for starters to ensure the user can't type wrong data? If you really use Blazor you can handle additional validation on the client. Same with pure JS.

Comment: The question is how to validate per keystroke.  I used time as an example but I am looking for validating a field as they type and prevent characters from even being typed.  I know it is possible but I do not know how to do that in this platform which is why I asked the question.  If you can point me in the right direction for a better way to validate any field per keystroke please do so.  I have searched and haven't found a way to do this on my own other than what I posted.

Comment: This code doesn't answer the question. There's no reason to call the server to perform validation per keystroke. Do you use Blazor or not though? If you do, why not handle the keystroke events *in the component*? If you use Blazor Server all events are already handled by the server anyway

Comment: Have you checked [Validating an input on keypress instead of on change in Blazor](https://www.meziantou.net/validating-an-input-on-keypress-instead-of-on-change-in-blazor.htm) ?